# Responsive div to stay in nested div doesnt work

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

The button will not stay with the image when I adjust the size of the browser. I tried the `position:absolute`in the img div and the responsive didn't work well with the position property. Obviously the `float:left` doesn't work either as written in CSS.

```css
.section6 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.img-group img {
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div.bg-bar {
  margin-top: -150px;
  max-height: auto;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #7290ab;
  z-index: 3;
}

.section6 button {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 330px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section6">
  <button>REQUEST AN INTERPRETER</button>
  <div class="img-group"><img src="http://dignityworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/group-people-standing-copyspace-7235283.jpg" alt="World-class SVRS interpreters"></div>
  <div class="bg-bar"></div>
</section>
```

See on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/L4hqrL8p/3/) of what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using fixed sizing units and this is not how you make responsive pages.

If you want the button to stay in the middle, you have to position it absolutely inside the relative div.

Something like this:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.relative {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #0fc0fc;
  animation: reduce 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  height: 50px;
}

button.centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  
  /* Kind of makes the anchor point of the element to be in the horizontal center */
  transform: translateX(-50%);

}

@keyframes reduce {
  0%,
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">

  <button class="centered">I'm in the middle</button>

</div>
```

Comment: LOL - love the animation! That worked for me - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are better off changing the image to be a background image on that div and moving the button to be inside of it.

HTML:

```
<section class="section6">
    <div class="img-group"><button>REQUEST AN INTERPRETER</button></div>
    <div class="bg-bar"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.section6 { 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin-top: 0;  
  }

.img-group { 
  z-index: 2; 
  text-align: right; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://dignityworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/group-people-standing-copyspace-7235283.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 370px;
  }

div.bg-bar { 
  margin-top: -150px; 
  max-height: auto;
  height: 150px; 
  background-color: #7290ab; 
  z-index: 3; 
  }

.section6 button { 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 5;
  top: 100px; 
  margin-right: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I dont want to use background image because of SEO tracking system.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

---

HTML:

```
<section class="section6">
    <div class="img-group">
         <img src="http://dignityworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/group-people-standing-copyspace-7235283.jpg" alt="World-class SVRS interpreters">
         <button>REQUEST AN INTERPRETER</button>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-bar"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.section6 { 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin-top: 0;
}

.img-group {
  position: relative;
}

.img-group img { 
  text-align: center; 
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.img-group button { 
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-left: -75px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

div.bg-bar { 
  margin-top: -150px; 
  max-height: auto;
  height: 150px; 
  background-color: #7290ab; 
}
```